# How to make an np.array in numba with input-dependent rank?

Tags: numpy, numba

I would like to `@numba.njit` this simple function that returns an array with a shape, in particular a rank, that depends on the input `i`:
E.g. for `i = 4` the shape should be `shape=(2, 2, 2, 2, 4)`

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def make_array_numba(i):
    shape = np.array([2] * i + [i], dtype=np.int64)
    return np.empty(shape, dtype=np.int64)

make_array_numba(4).shape
```

I tried many different ways, but always fail at the fact that I can't generate the `shape` tuple that `numba` wants to see in `np.empty` / `np.reshape` / `np.zeros` /...
In normal `numpy` one can pass lists / np.arrays as the `shape`, or I can generate a tuple on the fly such as `(2,) * i + (i,)`.

Output:

```
>>> empty(array(int64, 1d, C), dtype=class(int64))
 
There are 4 candidate implementations:
      - Of which 4 did not match due to:
      Overload in function '_OverloadWrapper._build.<locals>.ol_generated': File: numba/core/overload_glue.py: Line 131.
        With argument(s): '(array(int64, 1d, C), dtype=class(int64))':
       Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
         TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
       No implementation of function Function(<intrinsic stub>) found for signature:
        
        >>> stub(array(int64, 1d, C), class(int64))
        
       There are 2 candidate implementations:
         - Of which 2 did not match due to:
         Intrinsic of function 'stub': File: numba/core/overload_glue.py: Line 35.
           With argument(s): '(array(int64, 1d, C), class(int64))':
          No match.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not possible only with `@njit`**. The reason is that Numba needs to set a type for the array independently of variable values so to compile the function and only then execute it. The thing is the *dimension of an array is part of its type*. Thus, here, Numba cannot find the type of the array since it is dependent of a value that is not a *compile-time constant*.

The only way to solve this problem (assuming you do not want to linearize your array) is to recompile the function for each possible `i` which is certainly overkill and completely defeat the benefit of using Numba (at least in your example). Note that `@generated_jit` can be used in such a case when you really want to recompile the function for different values or input types. I strongly advise you not to use it for your current use-case. If you try, then you will have other similar issues due to the array not being indexable using a runtime-defined variables and the resulting code will quickly be insane.

A more general and cleaner solution is simply to linearize the array. This means flattening it and perform some fancy indexing computation like `(((... + z) * stride_z) + y) * stride_y + x`. The size and the index can be computed at runtime independently of the typing system. Note that indexing can be quite slow but Numpy will not use a faster code in this case.